# Actual for "item" must be a variable - Ada

Tags: ada

```
procedure Summera(Int1: in Integer;
             Int2: in Integer;
             Summa: out Integer) is 
      
      
   begin
      
      Put("Mata in ett heltal: ");
  48  Get(Int1);
      Put("Mata in ett heltal: ");
  50  Get(Int2);
      Summa:= Int1 + Int2;
      Put("Du matade in heltalet: ");
      Put(Int1, Width=>0);
      Put(" och heltalet: ");
      Put(Int2, Width=>0);
      Put(" och summan blev ");
      
   end Summera;
```

I know there is something wrong but not really what. on the lines 48 and 50 which are I get the error message "actual for item must be a variable." I am not allowed to put the string/text outside of the "subprogram" bit I have no idea how to make this work.
Why do I get this error messeage?

after begin I have this

```
Int1, Int2: Integer; 
Summa: Integer; 

begin 

Summera(Int1, Int2, Summa);
Put(Summa);

end program;
```

Answer (score 3):

The parameters

```ada
Int1: in Integer;
Int2: in Integer;
```

are in-parameters, ie. constants inside the procedure, whereas Get expects a variable in order to store the result. Maybe you meant for them to be local variables instead? Or `in out` parameters?

Comment: oh wow thanks, can I somehow do it without doing in out or is this the only way?

Answer (score 3):

Int1 and Int2 do not belong as parameters to the procedure Summera. Modify the procedure as follows:

```ada
procedure Summera(Summa: out Integer) is 
   Int1 : Integer;
   Int2 : Integer;
begin
      
   Put("Mata in ett heltal: ");
   Get(Int1);
   Put("Mata in ett heltal: ");
   Get(Int2);
   Summa:= Int1 + Int2;
   Put("Du matade in heltalet: ");
   Put(Int1, Width=>0);
   Put(" och heltalet: ");
   Put(Int2, Width=>0);
   Put(" och summan blev ");
      
end Summera;
```

Int1 and Int2 are local variables of procedure Summera. Your version cannot modify the values of Int1 and Int2.

If you want to modify the values of Int1 and Int2 and see those modified values in your main procedure you will want to declare the values to be OUT parameters.

```ada
procedure Summera(Int1: out Integer; Int2: out Integer; Summa: out Integer) is 
begin
      
  Put("Mata in ett heltal: ");
  Get(Int1);
  Put("Mata in ett heltal: ");
  Get(Int2);
  Summa:= Int1 + Int2;
  Put("Du matade in heltalet: ");
  Put(Int1, Width=>0);
  Put(" och heltalet: ");
  Put(Int2, Width=>0);
  Put(" och summan blev ");
      
end Summera;
```

OUT parameter mode is used when your procedure does not care what the initial value of the parameter is when it is passed to the procedure, but it must provide a value for the parameters within the procedure.